# Is it possible to add a transition animation effect after the state changes in React

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, animation, react-hooks, react-state-management

I need to apply a sliding animation effect to a new thumbnail loaded in the slider.

I am unable to figure out how this can be acheived in React. Do I need to use CSS or can it be achieved with ReactJS only or do it requires the combination of both React and CSS.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: you can achieve this using react and css